# Native html elements throwing 'did you register component' error in vue

Tags: vue.js

I've got a native `<break>` element that I'm using in with a flexbox element. Vue is throwing:

```
vue.esm.js?efeb:578 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <break> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

How can I specify native html elements in Vue?

Comment: A native `<break>`? Do you mean a `<br>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ignoredElements`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ignoredElements):

> #### ignoredElements
>
> - **Type:** `Array<string | RegExp>`
> - **Default:** `[]`
> - **Usage:**
>
>   ```
>     Vue.config.ignoredElements = [
>       'my-custom-web-component',
>       'another-web-component',
>       // Use a `RegExp` to ignore all elements that start with "ion-"
>       // 2.5+ only
>       /^ion-/
>     ]
>   ```
>
>   Make Vue ignore custom elements defined outside of Vue (e.g., using
>   the Web Components APIs). Otherwise, it will throw a warning about an
>   `Unknown custom element`, assuming that you forgot to register a
>   global component or misspelled a component name.

In your case:

```
Vue.config.ignoredElements = ['break'];
```

Demo:

```js
Vue.config.ignoredElements = ['break'];
        
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  }
})
```

```css
break { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <break>I am inside break</break>
</div>
```